# Symfony. Как сделать валидацию полей формы с зависимостью от значений других полей?

Tags: php, symfony, ddd

Всем доброго времени суток!
Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что надо сделать валидацию формы сущности Post с определенной бизнес логикой.

**Что есть:**

- форма для редактирования св-в Post (публикация) которую может редактировать пользователь
- валидация сущности Post через аннотации
- у сущности Post есть признак публикации (published) и дата публикации (publishedAt)
- дата публикации обязательна и должна быть больше или равно текущий дате, если выставлен признак публикации
- если признак публикации снят, то дату публикации никак не валидируем

Вопрос! Можно ли как то сделать такую валидацию без написания собственного валидатора поля "дата публикации"?

```
class Post
{
  /**
     * @Assert\NotNull
     */
  public bool $published;
  
    /**
     * Как написать правила валидации для этого св-ва?
     * @Assert\DateTime
     */
  public \DateTime $publishedAt;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно через callback

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Context\ExecutionContextInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
class Post
{
...

/**
 * @Assert\Callback
 */
public function validate(ExecutionContextInterface $context, $payload)
{
    if ($this->published)
    {
        if (!$this->publishedAt || $this->publishedAt < (new \Datetime()))
        {
            $context->buildViolation('Сообщение о ошибке')
               ->atPath('publishedAt ')
               ->addViolation();
        }
    }

}
...
```